# Does כבוד המת apply to gentiles? What about during war?

Tags: halacha-theory, death, parts-of-the-body

[Kavod HaMet](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA) is a halachic rubric which includes sensitive and dignified treatment of a corpse. I would like to know if this principle includes the prohibition for Jews to treat the corpses of gentiles in an insensitive or undignified way, and if so, would that apply equally during a time of war. Do any commentaries or halachic authorities discuss this?

Comment: Chazal (and the Navi for that matter) discuss how the reward of Yefes includes the army of Gog being buried: וְיֶפֶת זָכָה לִקְבוּרָה לְבָנָיו, שֶׁנֶאֱמַר אֶתֵּן לְגוֹג מְקוֹם שָׁם קֶבֶר

Comment: King David is praised for burying the corpses of slain (non-Jewish) enemies after the battle. (Someone help me out here? It's a midrash explaining some verse in Shmuel Bet about his renown.) Of course in the heat of battle itself, the living have to take precedence over the dead, but even so, I can't see any military advantage in actively mutilating a body (thus, it would be prohibited).

Comment: @Shalom advantages would be to terrorize / deter the enemy

Comment: @rikitikitembo I can't cite a source off the top of my head on that, but I will quote R' Asher Weiss shlit'a in a similar vein, noting that the staff poskim for the Israeli military and intelligence services consult with him. He said as much as we might want to say "go kill this terrorist after he's already been apprehended", any benefit is vastly outweighed by the cost to Israel's moral authority. Imho the same should apply here as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

[Amos 2:1](https://%20https://www.sefaria.org/Amos.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

> כֹּ֚ה אָמַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֔ה עַל־שְׁלֹשָׁה֙ פִּשְׁעֵ֣י מוֹאָ֔ב וְעַל־אַרְבָּעָ֖ה לֹ֣א אֲשִׁיבֶ֑נּוּ עַל־שׇׂרְפ֛וֹ עַצְמ֥וֹת מֶלֶךְ־אֱד֖וֹם לַשִּֽׂיד׃

> So said G-d; I [could tolerate] three sins of Moav, but not this fourth: that [its king] burned the bones of the King of Edom to plaster.

That sure sounds like intentionally mutilating a corpse, even a non-Jewish enemy one, is abhorrent.

(Yes, there are a lot of commentaries and different ways of reading it...)

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer the question of if Jewish people have a halachic imperative to treat non-Jewish corpses with kavod hamet

Comment: If one non-Jewish nation is called out by G-d as an unbearable act for mutilating the corpse of another one, you don't think the same prohibition applies to Jews?

Comment: by that logic Yoshiahu should not have defiled the bones of the prophets of Baal but he is praised for having done so in 2 Melachim 23

Comment: Thats only a source you cant defile a corspe. But you dont see you need to give is special honor and respect.